# How to call a function from an URL with a path containing "?" and "&"

Tags: regex, api, firebase, oauth, get

I'm working on a project with Firebase functions.
I get this URL path:

```
URL path: /callback-dev?code=777777777777&state=77777777777
```

I'm able to call the general function "app", but can't call the specific GET request I need, and being able to use the URL info:

```
app.get('/callback-dev*', (req, res) => {
oauth2.authorizationCode.getToken({
    code: req.query.code,
...
```

I have looked at RegEx, but really can't get my mind around it. Would really appreciate some help!
Thanks!

edit: I use Express.js v 4.x, which I read that uses {0,} instead of *, but it isn't working either.

Comment: So what are you trying to match?

Comment: Considering that the first parameter of the app.get is a regex, that won't work as you expect. That will match `/callback-de`, `/callback-dev`, `/callback-devv`, `/callback-devvv`, etc. Since `*` means 0 or more times. For matching a literal `?` you need to scape it as `\?` since `?` means 0 or 1 times in regex. You'll probably want something like this: `/callback-dev\?code=\d+&state=\d+`